# html\js Multi Choice Table Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, import-from-csv

I have 250,000 (250K) query lines. Some kind of a Table with ~10 columns.
The data is CSV and converted to HTML Table.

I need an idea\framework\sample how to be able to sort and filter it,

- Global Search
- multi choice filter category : (multi choice list\checkboxes)
- Like on best buy, in Laptops, you have screen size, and you can choose 13", 15" and it shows results accordingly.
- price\year range filter like  '|--------|' (that can be moves from both sides)

It have to be responsive, and I prefer local, like js \ jQuery and stuff.

Most of the scripts I found have only search and column sort, and it's very complicated to add custom filters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of custom filtering with dummy data just to give insight into how it's done. You can also potentially do your filtering by hiding/showing rows, but for the sake of speed here I'm just re-rendering the table each time after filtering.

The crux of it is this statement inside of the `filterData` function:

```
return data.filter(row => {
  for(let key in options){
    if(row[key] != options[key]) return false
  }
  return true
})
```

Where options looks like `{ eyeColor: "green", age: 35 }`, for example. You're just looping through your filter dropdowns, grabbing the key/value pair for each active filter, and then filtering your data against that.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "_id": "5b5f589b2340829388c09823",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "e2dc9a1d-7e37-4d2c-b97d-fb3607f9b388",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,995.31",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Tami Price",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "PHOTOBIN",
    "email": "tamiprice@photobin.com",
    "phone": "+1 (856) 427-2164",
    "address": "360 Wythe Place, Hannasville, Tennessee, 896",
    "about": "Qui non reprehenderit esse ut Lorem dolor dolore incididunt laborum cupidatat adipisicing. Mollit adipisicing esse ad voluptate in esse deserunt ut ut excepteur enim laborum. Duis mollit amet irure minim elit enim ad sunt. Eiusmod anim officia nisi consequat eiusmod exercitation non non velit non. Amet sunt qui qui cupidatat minim proident id ea fugiat excepteur id. Irure dolor qui aliqua cupidatat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-02-20T04:52:56 +05:00",
    "latitude": -3.23247,
    "longitude": 139.287912,
    "tags": [
      "deserunt",
      "amet",
      "elit",
      "dolor",
      "ipsum",
      "nostrud",
      "aute"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Carolina Pennington"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bartlett Forbes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Helene Rivera"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Tami Price! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b5f589b8905b957f15fedd3",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "da22124e-faa3-4c7b-a574-d897768c7c47",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,550.38",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 32,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Misty Bowers",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "NEBULEAN",
    "email": "mistybowers@nebulean.com",
    "phone": "+1 (934) 544-2138",
    "address": "296 Albemarle Road, Lindisfarne, Wyoming, 403",
    "about": "Adipisicing mollit excepteur est commodo mollit ut excepteur aliqua consectetur tempor laboris excepteur. Sunt veniam non velit elit cillum ullamco culpa incididunt nisi ipsum consectetur. Do culpa ea dolore elit eu id dolor exercitation.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-02-11T11:17:11 +05:00",
    "latitude": -33.028953,
    "longitude": -165.893086,
    "tags": [
      "cupidatat",
      "mollit",
      "dolor",
      "velit",
      "exercitation",
      "aliquip",
      "consectetur"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Higgins Frye"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stacie Patel"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Carmen Nunez"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Misty Bowers! You have 7 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b5f589b6e23f459ca3b81cd",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "3b029252-1c8d-4c4a-a4d4-87dc779e6fcb",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,847.74",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 31,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Craft Mullins",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "EPLOSION",
    "email": "craftmullins@eplosion.com",
    "phone": "+1 (826) 436-3905",
    "address": "218 Grand Avenue, Joes, Guam, 9205",
    "about": "Dolore commodo aute ipsum cillum occaecat irure mollit culpa fugiat et adipisicing qui. In ex eu labore incididunt id exercitation occaecat aliquip enim elit. Mollit aliqua ut culpa cillum. Aliqua sunt ipsum culpa pariatur ex elit id consectetur Lorem ad mollit aliquip voluptate laboris. Reprehenderit dolore sunt sit nulla.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-03-28T06:51:13 +04:00",
    "latitude": 46.812708,
    "longitude": -54.047492,
    "tags": [
      "aute",
      "minim",
      "Lorem",
      "sit",
      "minim",
      "ex",
      "mollit"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Love Crawford"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ladonna Middleton"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Benton Horne"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Craft Mullins! You have 6 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b5f589b04a78795b168510d",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "41188be6-c65b-47ed-8061-2fe7f228f58e",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,147.18",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 32,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Kristine Simpson",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "SULFAX",
    "email": "kristinesimpson@sulfax.com",
    "phone": "+1 (989) 414-3537",
    "address": "468 Cheever Place, Bergoo, Oklahoma, 8841",
    "about": "Adipisicing sunt occaecat consectetur ex exercitation consequat esse qui non laborum aliquip et laboris. Officia cillum et incididunt quis cillum enim ea in qui aliqua cupidatat ut dolore anim. Mollit culpa occaecat aliquip deserunt ex.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-04-26T06:02:45 +04:00",
    "latitude": -22.939072,
    "longitude": 135.212528,
    "tags": [
      "est",
      "dolor",
      "aute",
      "elit",
      "mollit",
      "fugiat",
      "consectetur"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Wooten Rich"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ball Fernandez"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cathryn Fulton"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Kristine Simpson! You have 1 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b5f589b87ad8ae689aa2639",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "6a1da7a5-66c0-4fc6-a424-92add50eaeef",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,652.13",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 30,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Noelle Winters",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "MICROLUXE",
    "email": "noellewinters@microluxe.com",
    "phone": "+1 (937) 554-3121",
    "address": "592 Stillwell Avenue, Clara, New Mexico, 297",
    "about": "Duis sint excepteur aute ex mollit aliquip commodo dolore exercitation ad qui est in. Exercitation esse in reprehenderit nulla deserunt. Laborum voluptate commodo enim veniam qui nostrud. Labore fugiat est labore ex est elit veniam sint tempor veniam cupidatat elit velit officia. Consectetur in est pariatur incididunt fugiat fugiat officia in excepteur. Culpa eu proident quis aliquip veniam aute excepteur ex amet eu.\r\n",
    "registered": "2018-02-27T07:48:49 +05:00",
    "latitude": -29.457437,
    "longitude": 33.52719,
    "tags": [
      "dolor",
      "cillum",
      "consequat",
      "officia",
      "eu",
      "nostrud",
      "fugiat"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Roxie Burt"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Priscilla Olsen"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bridgette Bray"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Noelle Winters! You have 6 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b5f589be181e8b38501ab88",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "6ad40fbb-8872-4f8c-bc5e-17226e255a9c",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,431.56",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 22,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "John Mcfarland",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "CAPSCREEN",
    "email": "johnmcfarland@capscreen.com",
    "phone": "+1 (923) 459-3323",
    "address": "390 Menahan Street, Farmers, District Of Columbia, 3239",
    "about": "Quis eu dolore irure anim voluptate sint aliqua reprehenderit est culpa. Cupidatat velit qui quis id consequat id voluptate. Velit est laboris velit mollit amet ullamco. Minim occaecat eiusmod eu officia consectetur ea fugiat sit consequat in aliqua mollit. Eiusmod ut anim excepteur ullamco cupidatat aliqua. Ea sunt qui incididunt commodo dolore labore eiusmod exercitation. Ut aute Lorem consequat sunt proident do excepteur.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-10-03T10:41:12 +04:00",
    "latitude": 7.189025,
    "longitude": 154.651965,
    "tags": [
      "deserunt",
      "cupidatat",
      "duis",
      "excepteur",
      "sunt",
      "tempor",
      "est"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Hamilton Morrison"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Margarita Dominguez"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Carey Atkinson"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, John Mcfarland! You have 7 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
]


const keys = [
  'name', 'email', 'age', 'eyeColor', 'gender'
]

const table = document.querySelector('table')
const tableHeader = document.createElement('tr')
const tableBody = document.createElement('tbody')
tableHeader.innerHTML = keys.map(key => `<th>${key}</th>`).join("")

table.appendChild(tableHeader)
table.appendChild(tableBody)

function fillTableData(dataset){
  tableBody.innerHTML = dataset.map(row => {
    return `<tr>${keys.map(key => `<td>${row[key]}</td>`).join("")}</tr>`
  }).join("")
}

fillTableData(data)

//generate filters
document.getElementById('filters').innerHTML = keys.map(key => {
  const options = data.reduce((arr, row) => {
    let val = row[key]
    if(arr.indexOf(val) < 0) arr.push(val)
    return arr
  }, []).sort()
  return `<label>${key}<select data-filter="${key}"><option value=""> </option>${options.map(option => `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`).join("")}</select></label>`
}).join("")

//filter function
function filterData(){
  const options = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll('select[data-active="active"]'), (obj, elem) => {
    obj[elem.getAttribute('data-filter')] = elem.value
    return obj
  }, {})
  console.log(options)
  return data.filter(row => {
    for(let key in options){
      if(row[key] != options[key]) return false
    }
    return true
  })
}
//set up filtering
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('select'), elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.value) this.setAttribute('data-active', 'active')
    else this.removeAttribute('data-active')
    
    fillTableData(filterData())
  })
})
```

```html
<table></table>
<br><br>
<div id="filters"></div>
```